# Automate the import of an IIF into Quickbooks

Tags: quickbooks

I need to be able to import an IIF file into a QuickBooks 2008 application, via a .NET application. I do not know the first thing about Quickbook automation.

Where should I look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIF files are deprecated in favour of a more fully featured API.

See question 20 here - https://developer.intuit.com/blog/2015/03/03/top-20-intuit-developer-questions or question 4 here - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0250_qb/0010_get_oriented/faqs

Comment: Thank you, but my clients are using IIF files now (with .csv) extensions, manually importing them successfully. I need to simply kick start the process and get a status of the import, with my .NET code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're integrating a website, you can use this Web Connector framework to help get you started with the QuickBooks SDK: 
http://idnforums.intuit.com/messageview.aspx?catid=56&threadid=11040&enterthread=y

Comment: It will be a desktop application.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a way to automate the actual import functionality of the QuickBooks app itself. You can certainly import the IIF files in your .NET code and then send the data to QuickBooks via the SDK.

QuickBooks has an IIF import kit that you can download. In it you will find details of the file format along with example IIF files. I don't have QuickBooks in front of me now, but you can find the download link by searching for IIF in the QuickBooks online help.

If that won't meet the needs of your client, then you might want to post in the [Intuit Developer Network forums](http://idnforums.intuit.com/). They should be able to answer the question definitively.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, they are importing IIF manually now, and I just want to automate that (I would rather avoid having to read the file and calling an API). I would rather call an API with the location of the IIF file. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I was in your position once and I decided to go with this 3rd-party component: http://www.nsoftware.com/ibiz/quickbooks/default.aspx

This component make it almost trivial to interact with QuickBooks. They also have sample code, help files, and a knowledge base.

Comment: I contacted nsoftware.com and they recommend cdata.com  ( am guessing they are owned by the same company now).